# A: Hide rows in Excel VBA when target cell contents are deleted

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a VBA in excel that hides or un-hides rows on other worksheets based on the content of target cell specific drop-down lists.  The drop down lists are meant to be dynamic, and users will occasionally change the responses.  Everything works well when responses are changed *except* when a user might delete previously entered content within a target cell with the delete button.  If this occurs, the hide/un-hide feature on the other sheets doesn't react.

Is there a line of code I can use to make True/False a hidden row command based on a user simply deleting content in a target cell (or multiple target cells if the user was to try to clear the whole front-end form by deleted content across all the drop down lists in all targeted cells?)?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Doesn't a Data validation list allow you the option to turn off *'Ignore blanks'* ?

Comment: I've got "Ignore blanks" set-up in the Data Validation, and also a line of VBA code that runs "hidden - True" when "".  Neither of these things seem to help this particular problem though.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, you want to **turn off 'Ignore blanks'**. If that isn't producing the correct results then I guess you are pretty much on your own until such time that you can get permission to post the super-secret Worksheet_Change code that performs these actions.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do, so far it sounds like nothing more than AutoFilter.  Could  you post some examples, like perhaps a before/after screenshots?

Comment: Alright, I had a chance to check my Data Validation lists, and somewhat embarrassingly - Jeeped was right.  I hadn't turned off the "Ignore blanks" in that set of cells even though I thought I had.  So, thanks Jeeped!